# Pesquisa sql com vários campos em java

Tags: java, sql

Como fazer uma pesquisa sql em java que envolva vários argumentos?
Exemplo: quero pesquisar todas pessoas com nacionalidade angolana, com o curso de ciências da Computação e que têm dois ou mais anos de experiência profissional.

Eu estou usando assim: `select * from candidato where nome like ?`, mas quando aumento mais campos retorna erro.

Este é o meu método de pesquisa:

```
public List<Dados_Cadastro> getLista(String nome) throws SQLException{
     String sql="select * from candidato where nome like ?";
 PreparedStatement stm = this.conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
 stm.setString(1, nome);
 ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();

 List<Dados_Cadastro>nova_lista = new ArrayList<Dados_Cadastro>();
 while(rs.next()){
  Dados_Cadastro cadastro =new Dados_Cadastro();

 cadastro.setNome_cadastro(rs.getString("nome"));
 cadastro.setGenero_cadastro(rs.getString("genero"));
 cadastro.setData_nasc_cadastro(rs.getString("nasc"));
 cadastro.setCbox_nacion_cadastro(rs.getString("nacionalidade"));
 cadastro.setCbox_nivel_cadastro(rs.getString("n_academico"));
 cadastro.setCurso_cadastro(rs.getString("curso"));
 cadastro.setEmpresa_cadastro(rs.getString("empresa"));
 cadastro.setCbox_exper_cadastro(rs.getString("experiencia"));
 cadastro.setIdent(Long.valueOf(rs.getString("ident")));
nova_lista.add(cadastro);
 }
 rs.close();
 stm.close();
 return nova_lista;
 }
```

Comment: Essa consulta vai para um sistema de produção ou é somente estudo?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode numerar os parâmetros, por exemplo:

```
select * from candidato where nome like ?1 AND genero = ?2
```

e depois informar os parâmetros:

```
stm.setString(1, nome);
stm.setString(2, genero);
```

Comment: Sua solução é melhor que a do Ikaro, mas você podia desenvolver ela um pouco mais para ajudar o @user44631.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM candidato WHERE nome LIKE '%'+getNome_cadastrado+'%';`

O sinal **%** é usado para definir wildcards (letras em falta) antes e após o padrão.

Comment: Não sei se entendi, devo fazer assim?

Comment: Especifique a parte que você não entendeu que eu posso lhe explicar melhor !

Comment: com esse código: select * from candidato where nome like ?. Eu apenas consigo consultar informando o nome cadastrado, mas eu gostaria de incluir na pesquisa outros atributos como: nacionalidade e experiência.

Comment: Ahh Sim ! Basta você colocar `AND`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM candidato WHERE nome LIKE '%'+getNome_cadastrado+'%' AND nacionalidade = '+getNacionalidade+';` Basta você ir colocando o `AND` e atribuindo os atributos que você quer consulta

Comment: Ou seja: eu quero que ele me mostra todos registos de pessoas com nacionalidade x, com experiência y

Comment: Caso tenha atributos de uma outra tabela, você tem que procurar por `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Ok, vou experimentar.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM candidato WHERE nome LIKE '%'+getNome_cadastrado+'%' AND nascionalidade = '+getNacionalidade+'  AND experiencia = '+getExperiencia+';`

Comment: Funcionou Valeu mano.

Comment: Qualquer coisa é só chamar... To aq pra ajudar

Comment: @user44631, dê uma espiada na resposta do Júlio Neto. Ele usa prepared statements, como seu código original, o que é mais seguro e eficiente que a concatenação de strings que o Ikaro propos.

Concatenação de string abre espaço para ataques de SQL injection e nunca deve ser usado.

Comment: Valeu pela dica  lpacheco, estou mesmo precisando dessas luzes todas. Eu sou apenas um iniciante.